# Regex to match any character except trailing spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I'm using this `/\([^\S\n]*(.*)[^\S\n]*\)/` regex to match what is inside brackets, and it works good except when there are trailing spaces, it matches them.

In for example `( test1 test2 )` I would like to match `test1 test2`, but I match `test1 test2_` (I wrote underscore, but it's trailing space).

Any idea how to remove this trailing space from my match?

I'm using PHP preg_replace function.

Comment: Why don't you just `preg_replace('/\s+$/','')` before you attempt to match? (Sorry if the syntax is not precisely right, I'm no PHPer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/
```

Result:

```
$reg = '/\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/';

var_dump( preg_replace( $reg, '$1', "( test1 test2 )" ) );

//string(11) "test1 test2"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Just one question, what is the question mark stands for, is it 0 or once? How it combines with + which is 1 or more?

Comment: @umpirsky: It makes the quantifier (`+`) match the shortest possible match, not the longest (non-greedy/lazy). See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html.

Comment: @umpirsky it makes the preceding `+` non-greedy. Read about greediness here http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. This regex is removing first closing bracket, and I want last. Example `( test1 t3() test2)` becomes `test1 t3( test2)` and I want `test1 t3() test2`. Is that possible to achieve with regex?

Comment: Or at least make regex not fixing anything if there are more then one open/closed brackets in the input string.

Comment: @umpirsky make a new question with your real problem, if you want any kind of parenthesis/bracket parsing then you can't simply use a regex.

Comment: It would be nice if I can just leave string as is if there is more then one pair of brackets. Here is a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766387/regex-to-remove-outer-brackets

Answer (score 1):

What about just anchoring the expression to the end of your text?

```
/\([^\S\n]*(.*)[^\S\n]*\)$/
                         ^
```

No whitespace after `\)`.

Comment: I get same results with your regex. You can test it here http://php.umpirsky.com/. Function: `preg_replace`, regex: `/\([^\S\n]*(.*)[^\S\n]*\)$/`, replace: `\1`, subject: `( test1 test2 )`. It gives `test1 test2 ` with space at the end which I want to remove. Thanks.